# How to connect my immersion chiller to the faucet

Tags: wort-chiller

I'm trying to figure out how to connect some hose pipe to my kitchen faucet to pump water through an immersion chiller.

The faucet has a male-threaded tip which screws out, so I believe there should be a faucet -> hosepipe adaptor that I can find to make a secure connection. The piece has "a112.18.1" engraved on it, which may contain information on its dimensions, but my google-fu has not revealed anything useful there.

I've looked on Amazon, Home Depot, etc., and there are a lot of options (like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0002APTXG)) that look like they are roughly what I need; any ideas how I can figure out exactly the part to order?

Comment: Worth mentioning that in the end, I just got a 3/8" garden hose, with a connector to a standard hose fitting. The 3/8" ID hose fits onto my chiller, and then I just connect that to the hose. Also got an in-line shutoff valve, so I can turn the flow off without having to run down to the hose faucet outside.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're chiller has garden hose adaptors on it you will simply want one of these:
[Faucet Adaptor](http://www.northernbrewer.com/shop/faucet-adapter.html)
I haven't seen too many of these at the hardware store, but they are a common item at most LHBSs.

[image]

Comment: I picked one up at Home Depot

Comment: Yep, that's the sort of thing I linked to in my original question. I was more looking for suggestions for how to get the right piece (as there are a number of different faucet thread dimensions, and I regularly see people complaining that the one-size-fits-all didn't).

Comment: @baka, I couldn't see those on the Home Depot website, did you just take your aerator in and match the threads?

Comment: @Symmetric:  Yes, or they only had a couple of them and I got lucky and guessed the correct one, I can't remember.   I had also recently replaced my faucet, so I think it was a standard Delta size fitting or something.

Comment: I saw one at Lowes, looked more like the free spinning end of a hose but same exact principle. Good luck!!!!

Comment: Check the size of your hoses. Most of these with hose fittings use standard garden hoses fittings. I use 2 washing machine hoses for mine with an aerator to garden hose adaptor, just like the one above, and just like the ones you would get for a bottle washer. If you're not drinking the cooling water, you don't need potable water hoses, but they need to be able to handle hot water, as it will come out of the chiller very hot at first.

Answer (score 0):

If you can make it to a store, take off your aerator and take it with you to the suoer. Match it there to a male sink or thread,.then match they to the appropriate adaptor.

There were two other options to consider. One is to add another valve under the sink, by the shutoff valve. You can add a 't' and a second shutoff valve, then sweat our solder in a house pipe connector or QD after the valve.

You can also try using a 'quick shower' attachment that puts a rubber cup over the end of the faucet, just cut the other end of and house clamp to the chiller, but it can be touchy if too much flow comes out the faucet.

Comment: As mentioned above, I was hoping to avoid having to go to a store in the hopes that they have the piece I need. I was hoping to find a way of identifying the part I need ahead of time.